# No aspx controls show on page , only text , when browsing page from IIS, (C#,ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, controls

i have win 7 with internet explorer 8.

i have a Web application project in the VS2010, 
when i execute it using local port auto-asign port, the aspx page shows ok on the internet explorer.

when i run the same project from the IIS (Browsing the aspx page from the iis),
only the controls text is displays without the controls (colors and menus .. ) - although the source view shows that the tags exists.

is it a problem with the IIS 7 ?

Comment: Are you browsing on a local IIS installation or on a remote server? Are you browsing on the remote server or from your computer to the remote server?

Comment: Could you paste an example of what the source view showing the tag?

Comment: Have you verified that styles are being included?

Comment: did you also publish your stylesheets to the virtual directory? And if so, are you referencing them correctly from your aspx header?

Comment: "the tag exists", do you mean the html tag, or the asp.net server control tag (`<asp:Label>` etc)? If the latter, IIS isn't processing the asp.net pages.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: i created and application in IIS 7 that point to my project on the same computer, i'm right clicking the aspx file and chooses 'browse'. it also happen when i execute teh project in the VS (that also point to the aspx on the iis).

Comment: @jon,Rewinder: i dont have any styles i just use the default page that comes when opening a new web application in the studio ( the one with the "My ASP.NET Application" and the two menu buttons. i can see in the browser only the text , not the blue colors and the controls.

Comment: i Solved the problem by checking the "Static Content" checkbox in the win 7 "windows features".

i don't know what the "Static Content" does but it prevented my CSS from working in the IIS 7.

To all of you who had the same problem :

in Win 7 - IIS 7  

Go To Control Panel --> Programs --> "Turn windows Features on and off" --> Internet Information Services --> world wide web services --> Common HTTP Features --> check the "Static Content" Check box and restart the IIS.

this will enable CSS files in IIS 7

Wow! this was a heavy one! took me 3 days to solve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Solved the problem by checking the "Static Content" checkbox in the win 7 "windows features".

i don't know what the "Static Content" does but it prevented my CSS from working in the IIS 7.

To all of you who had the same problem :

in Win 7 - IIS 7

Go To Control Panel --> Programs --> "Turn windows Features on and off" --> Internet Information Services --> world wide web services --> Common HTTP Features --> check the "Static Content" Check box and restart the IIS.

this will enable CSS files in IIS 7

Wow! this was a heavy one! took me 3 day to solve!

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing. Do view source of the page and click on the link (you get this in Firefox) of the CSS or JS or IMAGE. If you get a 404, then it probably an issue of form authentication. If so, then you will have to check that the CSS/JS folder has the permission.

Comment: You can do this in IE as well. Use the dev console by pressing F12.

Comment: i Solved the problem by checking the "Static Content" checkbox in the win 7 "windows features".

i don't know what the "Static Content" does but it prevented my CSS from working in the IIS 7.

To all of you who had the same problem :

in Win 7 - IIS 7  

Go To Control Panel --> Programs --> "Turn windows Features on and off" --> Internet Information Services --> world wide web services --> Common HTTP Features --> check the "Static Content" Check box and restart the IIS.

this will enable CSS files in IIS 7

Wow! this was a heavy one! took me 3 days to solve!

Answer (score 0):

Was your site running in a project folder such as `localhost:65412/my_project_name/default.aspx` and is running on the root such as `http://www.example.com/default.aspx` on the live site?

Its probably just the paths being set up incorrectly between the two development environments.

The way around this is to ensure that your dev env matches the production environment. You can do this quite easily by following my tutorial here:

- [An easy way to keep your dev and live server urls in sync](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/10/easy-way-to-keep-your-dev-and-live.html)

After this your local site will probably break as well but when you have fixed the paths to your images and css it will then work correctly in both environments.

Comment: thank you rtpHarry but i dont have any environments, just my local computer. when i 'browse' the application fromm the IIS, i can see only the text of the default aspx page that comes with a new web application ("My ASP.NET Application")

Comment: i Solved the problem by checking the "Static Content" checkbox in the win 7 "windows features".

i don't know what the "Static Content" does but it prevented my CSS from working in the IIS 7.

To all of you who had the same problem :

in Win 7 - IIS 7  

Go To Control Panel --> Programs --> "Turn windows Features on and off" --> Internet Information Services --> world wide web services --> Common HTTP Features --> check the "Static Content" Check box and restart the IIS.

this will enable CSS files in IIS 7

Wow! this was a heavy one! took me 3 days to solve!